# BERT Model for reviews throwing an error. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

This is the [link to the tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/amazon-product-review-sentiment-analysis-using-bert/).
This is the [code](https://github.com/yashinaniya/NLP_Projects/blob/main/Amazon_product_sentiment_analysis.ipynb) specifically (I just opened in Colab and ran it - so I did not edit anything):

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 1483, in compute_loss  *
        return super().compute_loss(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss  **
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 263, in __call__
        y_t, y_p, sw = match_dtype_and_rank(y_t, y_p, sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 840, in match_dtype_and_rank
        if (y_t.dtype.is_floating and y_p.dtype.is_floating) or (

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

after this section of code:

```py
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5, epsilon=1e-08)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.compute_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(100).batch(16),
          epochs=2,
          batch_size=16,
          validation_data=val_dataset.shuffle(100).batch(16))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `compute_loss` method was renamed to `hf_compute_loss` in this PR:

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/15207

So your updated code should be:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5, epsilon=1e-08)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.hf_compute_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(100).batch(16),
          epochs=2,
          batch_size=16,
          validation_data=val_dataset.shuffle(100).batch(16))
```

Credit to Sadlig for this solution.

Source: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-dtype/19183/7